# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory .Magento 1.9 indexing error

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, installation, indexer

I have installed Magento 1.9 but when I am trying to run indexer command
I am getting following errors.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(128): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'mag1', 'mag1@123', Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(396): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#7 / in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 144
```

I am running

```
php shell/indexer.php
```

is it correct or anything else I have to run indexer command
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the server to **127.0.0.1** from **localhost**

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: No.i have changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 in my local.xml that didnt worked.